# How to set conditions for search in prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to create a site search in prepared statements,

Here is my code : Conditions for search

```
$whereSQL = $orderSQL = ''; 
if(!empty($_POST['keywords'])){ 
    $whereSQL = "WHERE title LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%'"; 
} 
if(!empty($_POST['sortBy'])){ 
    $orderSQL = " ORDER BY title ".$_POST['sortBy']; 
}else{ 
    $orderSQL = " ORDER BY title DESC "; 
}
```

This is how I add it to query :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ".$whereSQL.$orderSQL); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$rowCount= $stmt->rowCount();
```

Here is my question.
How can I use conditions safe way in prepared statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up an array of any bind parameters dynamically and then pass this to the `execute()`

As the only value you can bind is in the WHERE clause, you only need to alter than part...

```
$whereSQL = $orderSQL = ''; 
$bindParams = [];
if(!empty($_POST['keywords'])){ 
    $whereSQL = "WHERE title LIKE :title"; 
    $bindParams['title'] = '%'.$_POST['keywords'].'%';
} 

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ".$whereSQL.$orderSQL); 
// Pass values to statement
$stmt->execute($bindParams);
```

Comment: For order can use a whitelist, something like `$orderSQL = in_array($_POST['sortBy'], array('asc', 'desc')) ? $_POST['sortBy'] : 'DESC';`

Comment: It may be more simple: $orderSQL = strtoupper($_POST['sortBy']) == 'ASC'  ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

Comment: @Nigel Ren  So there is no way to prevent from using conditions in query ? Thanks